# How to write units when multiple terms are involved in a derivation?

Tags: soft-question, notation

Say I am going to write down the steps of some calculations to get the final value of $s$ from an equation like this:
$$ s = s_0 + \frac12 gt^2. $$
Let us say $s_0 = 20\,\mathrm{m}$, $g = 10\,\mathrm{ms^{-2}}$, and $t = 2\,\mathrm{s}$. What is the right way to write down the units in every step so that all the formula, LHS, and RHS are always consistent in terms of units?

#### Alternative 1

\begin{align*}
s &= s_0 + \frac12gt^2 \\
  &= 20\,\mathrm{m} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 10\,\mathrm{m\,s^{-2}} \cdot (2\,\mathrm{s})^2 \\
  &= 20\,\mathrm{m} + 20\,\mathrm{m} \\
  &= 40\,\mathrm{m}.
\end{align*}

#### Alternative 2

\begin{align*}
s &= s_0 + \frac12gt^2 \\
  &= 20\,\mathrm{m} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 10\,\mathrm{m\,s^{-2}} \cdot 2^2\,\mathrm{s^2} \\
  &= 20\,\mathrm{m} + 20\,\mathrm{m} \\
  &= 40\,\mathrm{m}.
\end{align*}

#### Alternative 2

\begin{align*}
s &= s_0 + \frac12gt^2 \\
  &= 20\,\mathrm{m} + \left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10 \cdot 2^2\right)\,\mathrm{m} \\
  &= 20\,\mathrm{m} + 20\,\mathrm{m} \\
  &= 40\,\mathrm{m}.
\end{align*}

#### Alternate 3

\begin{align*}
s &= s_0 + \frac12gt^2 \\
  &= \left(20 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 10 \cdot 2^2\right)\,\mathrm{m} \\
  &= 20\,\mathrm{m} + 20\,\mathrm{m} \\
  &= 40\,\mathrm{m}.
\end{align*}

Are all alternatives correct? Is there any alternative above or another alternative that is widely used in literature?

Comment: Alternative 1 is by far the clearest.

Comment: I agree - alternative 1.

Comment: I'm for #1 too but I'd rather use the cross symbol × instead of the dot to indicate the product

Answer (score 6):

There's no *right* way.  But I use and recommend Alternative #1 in the class I teach.  It keeps the value with the unit which makes it easier to go back and find mistakes.

**Addendum**

Another thing that I try to drill into them with only modest success is to *not* do "algebra-by-cross-out", but rather to write a complete new line for every step. Again, doing that improves readability and the finding of mistakes.  I absorbed that habit myself after a memorial service for [Henry Primakoff](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.2915405) at which framed pages of his notebooks were on display ... colorful visual delights in themselves.  It was said that he never skipped a step when doing calculations.  If it was good enough for Primakoff it was good enough for me.  I've been doing it ever since.

I'm pretty sure this disease is spread by well-meaning but misguided high school teachers.  High school teachers listen up:  don't do that.

Comment: garyp, when I taught high school physics, MANY students absolutely refused to show units on their numbers, even after repeated comments from me to do so.  Unfortunately, this meant that their work was difficult to follow, and when they had dimensional inconsistencies, they were unaware of it.  Such obstinate students are practically unteachable.  Do you teach at the high school or college level?

Comment: This isn't even limited to High school, I teach college undergrads and almost none of them ever keep the units, then wonder why they continue to get points off despite how many times I tell them to put units on. This even from upper level engineering students who typically come from very strict classes where their work is usually only accepted when extremely neat and detailed.

Comment: Does no one remember MCO?

Comment: @DavidWhite College level.  I would warn them that although I would be lenient on a timed exam, leaving out units can make it difficult to follow, which in turn makes it impossible to give partial credit.

Answer (score 0):

I perfectly agree with garyp: There is no right or wrong way to put the units into the equations. However, in my experience people tend to make mistakes, if they rewrite the equations. That's why I recommend

1. to convert all units to the standard SI units (no prefixes like nano or kilo),
2. do the insertion and calculation of the numbers as a side mark, where we do not include the units, and
3. finally just writing the  final result with the SI unit as the solution.

Hence, your calculation would read
$$
s = s_0 + \frac{1}{2}g t ^2 = \fbox{40m}
$$
and the side mark would read
$$
\left(20 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 10 \cdot 2^2\right)
= 20 + 20 = 40.
$$

Comment: You didn't show units on the numbers, which makes the work somewhat more difficult to follow.

Comment: @DavidWhite: Exactly this is my point: I do **not** expect from a student (at university level) that he/she shows me how to enter these values into the equation. Thus, I won't give you any credit for showing me how you do it. However, if you mess up (like forgetting the units in one step), I will penalise you even if the end result is correct. Hence, (1) do the calculation in such a way that it becomes simple for you, and (2) reduce the number of lines in which you might make mistakes. This is what I showed in my answer!

Comment: I have a different viewpoint.  When units are used on all numbers, it becomes immediately obvious when a dimensional inconsistency exists.  And yes, I realize that this slows students down a bit during a timed test.